# SwiftUI rectangle taking up the wrong amount of space

Tags: swift, swiftui

I made a comment feed for a subreddit I moderate and I wanted to make a vertical line on the left side of the comment underneath the title of the post in SwiftUI. I made the line using a rounded rectangle but the problem is instead of shaping itself to the height of the text, it is a certain height and makes the text conform to that height. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

---

#### Screenshot

[image: Here is an image of the problem]

---

#### Code

```
VStack {
  HStack {
    Text(comment.link_title ?? "")
      .font(.callout)
      .bold()
      .padding(.horizontal, 5)
      .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
    Spacer()
  }
  HStack {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2, style: .continuous)
      .frame(width: 3)
      .foregroundColor(Color("medGray"))
      .padding(.leading, 10)
    Text(comment.body ?? "")
      .font(.body)
      .padding(5)
      .foregroundColor(Color("black"))
    Spacer()
  }
}
```

---

Comment: try to add .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) to Hstack or main VStack

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686051/12299030 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/61028066/12299030?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply using an overlay.

Checkout the following example:

```
HStack {
    Text("Lorem ipsum")
        .font(.body)
        .padding(.leading, 20)
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    Spacer()
}.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 2, style: .continuous)
                        .frame(width: 3)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        .padding(.leading, 10),
          alignment: .leading)
```